# Can test In App purchase in simultor?

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

I created In App Purchase product app. When i test in simulator through test user account, i got Transaction failed error. Is In App Purchase allow to test simulator or only in device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't test it in simulator.

You get reach of prompt enter apple ID or Password for buying product, but its remaining process not allow in to simulatore that's why you got Prompt of Transaction failed error.

**You must test it In Device with relevant Provisioning code sign with your Test Apple id or password.**

Answer (score 0):

You can't test in simulator, you have to plug your device and test with it.

If you want to try anyway, the console remind you that you can't :

```
// WARNING: SKPaymentQueue does not work in the simulator
```